# undefined method `reject' for string when reading cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code, basically i want to save a cookie the first time a person submits the form, and the next time read from the cookie to populate the form.

```
 def new
    @detail = Detail.new(cookies[:detail])
 end
```

And the create method has

```
  def create
    @detail = Detail.new(params[:detail])

    if @detail.save
      cookies[:detail] = {
        value: params[:detail],
        expires: 30.days.from_now
      }
      redirect_to confirmation_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `reject' for #<String:0x007fbf5486ac48>
```

Comment: What line gives that error?

Comment: Line 5     @detail = Detail.new(cookies[:detail])

Comment: Detail initializer must be expecting a hash or something, but you are passing a cookie into it. Try Detail.new(cookie[:detail][:value]).

Comment: Does not work, if i try access the value i.e [:detail]["name"] i get back "name" and not the value. How ever if i check the cookies[:detail] looks like a hash